# Executing grep via Perl

Tags: perl, file-io, grep, line-by-line

I am new to Perl. I am trying to execute grep command with perl.

I have to read input from a file and based on the input, the grep has to be executed.

My code is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

#Reading input files line by line
open FILE, "input.txt" or die $!;
my $lineno = 1;
while (<FILE>) {

        print " $_";
        #This is what expected.
        #our $result=`grep -r Unable Satheesh  > out.txt`;
        our $result=`grep -r $_ Satheesh  > out.txt`;
        print $result

}
print "************************************************************\n";
```

But, if I run the script, it looks like a infinite loop and script is keep on waiting and nothing is printed in the out.txt file.

Comment: All the `grep` output is going into `out.txt`, not into `$result`.

Comment: Why are you using the `grep` command when Perl has a perfectly good built-in `grep` function?

Comment: Are you expecting Satheesh to be the pattern and $_ to be the directory to search in?  If so, I think you have those backwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it's hanging is because you forgot to use `chomp` after reading from `FILE`. So there's a newline at the end of `$_`, and it's executing two shell commands:

```
grep -r $_
Satheesh > out.txt
```

Since there's no filename argument to `grep`, it's reading from standard input, i.e. the terminal. If you type <kbd>Ctl-d</kbd> when it hangs, you'll then get an error message telling you that there's no `Satheesh` command.

Also, since you're redirecting the output of `grep` to `out.txt`, nothing gets put in `$result`. If you want to capture the output in a variable and also put it into the file, you can use the `tee` command.

Here's the fix:

```
while (<FILE>) {

        print " $_";
        chomp;
        #This is what expected.
        #our $result=`grep -r Unable Satheesh  > out.txt`;
        our $result=`grep -r $_ Satheesh | tee out.txt`;
        print $result

}
```